# Image downloaded with HttpClient is corrupt

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am trying to save an image from the web to local storage to be manipulated later, but it appears to be corrupt and attempting to open it with an external application fails. Opening the image in the webbrowser works completely normally. Thanks for any help.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var clientResponse = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUri);

var temp = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile file;
if ((await temp.GetFilesAsync()).Any(f => f.Name == "temp_image.png")) {
    file = await temp.GetFileAsync("tempcolorizer.png");
} else {
    file = await temp.CreateFileAsync("temp_image.png");
}
using (var fs = await file.OpenReadAsync())
using (var writer = new DataWriter(fs)) {
    writer.WriteBytes(clientResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `StoreAsync`:

```
using (var fs = await file.OpenReadAsync())
using (var writer = new DataWriter(fs)) {
  writer.WriteBytes(clientResponse);
  await writer.StoreAsync();
}
```